# error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Tags: cs50

```
if (i==15)
    {
        (f/(10(^)13)) ==34 || (f/(10(^)13)) ==37;
        printf("AMEX \n");
    }
```

I couldn't find what's wrong here. I get the error of "type name requires a specifier or qualifier" and "Expected expression"
The priority of == is greater than ^ but I've put ^ between brackets so it shall execute first.

Comment: What is "`(f/(10(^)13)) ==34 || (f/(10(^)13)) ==37;`" supposed to do?

Comment: i checks the length of the card number, if the length is 15, the f is the card number, which is divided by 10000000000000 and if the division result is either 34 or 37,  AMEX  will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Their are several problems in your  code:

- First `10(^)13` cannot be written, you should have write `10^13`
- The `^` operator is the bitwise xor. 
  So `10^13` will be evaluated to `7` (`1010b xor 1101b -> 0111b`), it's not what you want.
- You forgot the `if` in your test (and the `;` will cause you some trouble if you do not removed it when you add the `if`).

So if `f` is a 64 bits integer, the correct syntax of what you want is:

```
#define CARD_TYPE_POSITION 10000000000000
if (i==15)
{    
    if (((f/CARD_TYPE_POSITION) == 34) || ((f/CARD_TYPE_POSITION) == 37))
        printf("AMEX \n");
}
```

You can also compute the card type once:

```
#define CARD_TYPE_POSITION 10000000000000
if (i==15)
{    
    int card_type = f / CARD_TYPE_POSITION;
    if ((card_type == 34) || (card_type == 37))
        printf("AMEX \n");
}
```

Comment: i correct it but now I'm getting "Expression result unused"